# Doubts on how recursion works in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to do a recursive function in which i put a list of numbers as an input. and it should give as an output the number(**counter**) of sublists that have **subtotal** as the result of the numbers inside of them. I tried building a recursive function, and when I arrive at what I guess should be the base case, I have the right result (when debugging, at some point) in **counter**. But at the end of the function the value my **counter** is just 0. I know it's because of exiting calls, but haven't really understood how this works. What am I doing wrong with my code and how can I correct it?

```
  def count (lista,i,j,accumulatore,counter):
        if i > len(lista)-1: return counter
        else:
            if accumulatore < subtotal :
                if j > len(lista)-1:
                    i+=1
                    count (lista,i,i,0,counter)
                else:
                    accumulatore += lista[j]
                    j+=1
                    count(lista,i,j,accumulatore,counter)
            elif accumulatore == subtotal:
                counter+=1
                if j > len(lista)-1:
                    i+=1
                    count(lista,i,i,0,counter)
                else:
                    accumulatore+=lista[j]
                    j+=1
                    count(lista,i,j,accumulatore,counter)
            else: #accumulator > subtotal
                i+=1
                count(lista,i,i,0,counter)
```

Comment: I assume you meant for your function to be called `count`? You don't do anything with the recursive calls. E.g. the result of `count (lista,i,i,0,counter)` is just discarded. You need to assign the result of these calls somewhere

Comment: I'd recommend writing a fibonacci recursive solution (for small inputs) to get the hang of return values and stop conditions.

Comment: At the very least, you need to *return* the value returned by each recursive call: `return count(lista, i, i, 0, counter)`, for example.

Comment: You should provide an input and expected output. As it stands, this code can't run because `subtotal` isn't defined. It sort of looks like you're trying to implement something that would be more naturally done with a for loop or fold function, but it's unclear what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: ok I understood there is no base case in my code and this is not how you do a recursive function

Comment: @bogus You do actually have a base case: `if i > len(lista) -1:`. It's your iterative cases that are not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem are these calls in your code:

```
count (lista,i,i,0,counter)
```

Note that you're *calling* `count` but you're not returning the value anywhere except the base case. So, when your `else` clause ends, the function returns a default `None`.

It's a little unclear what you expect your inputs and outputs to be, but you can almost certainly simplify this function. Remember, for recursion the basic idea is to reduce the size of your problem until you hit some base case, and then use the response of the next-smallest-problem output to construct your own output.

For that reason, accumulators aren't usually part of a properly deployed recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it and it's working! subtotal has to be defined outside in this case

```
  def conta (lista,i,j,accumulatore,contatore):
        if i > len(lista)-1: return contatore
        else:
            if accumulatore < subtotal :
                if j > len(lista)-1:
                    return conta (lista,i+1,i+1,0,contatore)
                else:
                    return conta(lista,i,j+1,accumulatore+lista[j],contatore)
            elif accumulatore == subtotal:
                if j > len(lista)-1:
                    return conta(lista,i+1,i+1,0,contatore+1)
                else:
                    return conta(lista,i,j+1,accumulatore+lista[j],contatore+1)
            else: #caso in cui accumulatore > subtotale
                return conta(lista,i+1,i+1,0,contatore)
```

Edit : I'm running across recursion limit problems and am translating it to an iterative fun-ction